# Prerequisites for chiral Perturbation theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations, education, quantum-chromodynamics, perturbation-theory

I am Ms final year student.
Could you pls guide me for the prerequisites of the chiral Perturbation theory? I have studied Quantum Field theory up to large $N$ gauge theory and renormalizations. Now I would like to head towards the chiral perturbation theory.

Also, I would request for the textbook which gives the basics of chiral perturbation theory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [Introduction to Effective Field Theories, Aneesh Manohar](https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.05863)

These are his lecture notes from 2017 Les Houches School. He discusses in quite some detail the general features of EFTs, not just chiral PT. In particular there is a good exposition on power counting and regularization.

You can follow it up with

> A Primer for Chiral Perturbation Theory, Stefan Scherer & Matthias Schindler

which is based on Scherer's lecture notes, that apt45 mentioned in their answer.

And even though you have learnt renormalization, it might be helpful to take a second look at it as just a mathematical technique, without all the trappings of field theory. For that you can use

> [A Hint of Renormalization, B. Delamotte](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0212049).

Answer (score 1):

I think that your basis is good to start studying Chiral Perturbation Theory. Let me give you some references.
All standard textbooks cover the basics of Chiral Perturbation theory (CPT), but I suggest you to start from Effective Field Theories(EFTs). Indeed, the CPT is the most famous example of EFT and it's a good starting point to understand all the physics behind EFTs. 
The review by Georgi is a very good one, you can find it [here](http://www.people.fas.harvard.edu/~hgeorgi/review.pdf), read it.

Then, regarding Chiral Perturbation Theory, I suggest you the following references

> Matthew D. Schwartz, Quantum Field Theory and the Standard Model

- Chapter 22.3 : You can find a short introduction to the theory of mesons
- Chapter 28 : It treats spontaneous symmetry breaking and then it discuss shortly the Chiral Lagrangian.

> Introduction to Chiral Perturbation Theory, Stefan Scherer, 0210398 hep-ph

- This is more a review you can find on arXiv. It covers a lot of interesting topic. Try to read it.

> S.Weinberg, The Quantum Theory of Fields: Volume 2, Modern Applications

- Chapert 19: this is absolutely the best treatement about spontanous symmetry breaking and theory of mesons. I suggest you to read it when you will have a bit of familiarity with EFTs and CPT from the resources I gave you before.